# AngularJS ng-show with yes/no

Tags: angularjs

I have a div I'd like to show once a yes/no radio button is checked. The problem is when i click no. My ng-show is evaluating "no" as false and hiding.
I'd like do do something like this

```
    <div ng-show="IsYesOrNo">
```

But I end up having to do something like this:

```
    <div ng-show="IsYesOrNo=='yes' || IsYesOrNo=='no'">
```

I'm using 1.2.25. It looks like it actually works the way I expect it in 1.3.0-rc.3.

Is there a better way on how to build my ng-show?
Here's a plnkr I threw together demonstrating the behavior.

http://plnkr.co/edit/wjVi0GezlD21IVcCxG70

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about

```
<div ng-show="IsYesOrNo !== undefined">HasSet</div>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/qSNrNA1mMCFRFrpXOxPb?p=preview

Comment: Thanks, it's a prettier than what I had.

Answer (score 0):

May be a bit of a hack, but in your case you can use `.length`:

```
   <div ng-show="IsYesOrNo.length">HasSet</div>
```

See [Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/HxENxI8MkyN80wxlfHJc?p=preview)

Comment: Neat idea, but I'm going to go with the other answer. Thanks.